# Git: Find code in a file's history

Tags: git, file, find, history

I'd like to find a string in a file's history in git, i know that to find it in all files is like this:

```
git grep whatever $(git rev-list --all)
```

But i'd like to find it only in the history of a file, for example i want to know how to find the string 'preg_match' in the file: datacar.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use
[the pickaxe](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

```
git log -S preg_match -- datacar.php
```

and if you want the diffs

```
git log -p -S preg_match -- datacar.php
```

More info

```
-S<string>

    Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of 
    <string>. Note that this is different than the string simply 
    appearing in diff output; see the pickaxe entry in gitdiffcore(7)
    for more details.
```

Comment: I did it, but here's the error i get: fatal: ambiguous argument 'DataCarSoaker.php': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'